# Remover todos los elementos de una lista excepto el primero

Tags: python, lista

estoy comenzando a practicar en Python y buscando la forma de editar listas que se encuentran dentro de una lista me he topado con el problema de que quiero eliminar todos los elementos excepto el primero de cada lista (Y sin tener que enviar cada primer elemento a una lista nueva). Alguna sugerencia? Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
Listas2 =[["Numero 10", "Numero 1"], ["Numero 11", "Numero 2"], ["Numero 14", "Numero 3"]]


for x in Listas2:
    x[:] = [i.replace("Numero", "") for i in x]
    x[:] = sorted([float(i) for i in x])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres eliminar todo menos el primer elemento entonces solo quédate con el primer elemento. Una comprensión de lista basta.

```py
Listas2 =[["Numero 10", "Numero 1"], ["Numero 11", "Numero 2"], ["Numero 14", "Numero 3"]]

lista = [x[0] for x in Listas2]
print(lista)
```

Si quieres modificar la lista original (`Listas2`) entonces solo haces

```py
Listas2 =[["Numero 10", "Numero 1"], ["Numero 11", "Numero 2"], ["Numero 14", "Numero 3"]]

Listas2 = [x[0] for x in Listas2]
print(Listas2)
```

Teniendo como resultado:

```py
['Numero 10', 'Numero 11', 'Numero 14']
```

El reemplazo de la cadena también lo puedes hacer dentro de la comprensión de lista

Comment: Estrictamente hablando, la comprensión de listas crea una nueva lista. Asignarla a `lista` o  `Listas2` tiene el mismo costo; es simplemente una asignación de punteros por debajo. Lo que pide el OP no tiene sentido.

Comment: claramente, yo lo interpreté como no crear muchas variables o asignar una nueva lista a una nueva variable :D

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues en el caso que dentro de la lista halla listas con más de dos elementos lo podemos iterar así:
Recorriendo la lista y pasarle una función con un  bucle while que eliminé el último elemento de cada sublista hasta que quede 1 con el método len().

```
listas2 =[["Numero 10", "Numero 1"], ["Numero 11", "Numero 2"], ["Numero 14", "Numero 3"]]

def salto(lista):
  while len(lista)>1:
    lista.pop()

for i in listas2:
  salto(i)
print(listas2)
```